# Authenticate users across Django projects - where to begin?

Tags: python, django

I'm in the process of building several Django based web applications for the same client.   What I would like to do is set up an authentication server so that user credentials can be shared among django projects e.g. Jan Doe creates account for App-A and can use the same un and pw to log in to App-B.

[Django packages](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/authentication/) is only somewhat helpful as I can't tell from the package descriptions if the package will help me do what I want to do or not.

I'm very inexperienced in this area so I don't even know if my questions are appropriate, but here goes:

Should I even be looking at django packages?
Would looking for a python based auth server be more appropriate?
Where should I start to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need a separate package. Just use Django's built-in multi-database handling. Check out: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/.

Essentially, you designate one of your databases as the one that's going to store the user data and make sure that database is added to each of your other projects. Then set up a router that checks for `app_label=='auth'` and route to the "user" database for those instances. There's an example in the docs.